# boost asio exception: use_private_key_file: key values mismatch

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, openssl, boost-asio

I'm using the [example server from boost asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp), and I'm failing to run that and getting this error,

> Exception: use_private_key_file: key values mismatch

I'm changing ABSOLUTELY NOTHING in the program, except for keys and port.

I'm willing to use my own key authority, and it seems like there's a problem in the library, where it's not excluded that I could be doing something fundamentally wrong, so please assist.

In the program, I use the following lines for the keys:

```
context_.use_certificate_chain_file("../sslkeys/server.crt");
context_.use_private_key_file("../sslkeys/server.key", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
context_.use_tmp_dh_file("../sslkeys/dh512.pem");
```

And to create these keys, I do the following:

1- Create Certificate Authority (CA)

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -key ca.key -out ca.crt -days 36500
```

2- Create server key and sign it with the authority key

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in server.csr -signkey ../sslca/ca.key -out server.crt
cp server.key server.key.secure
openssl rsa -in server.key.secure -out server.key
openssl dhparam -out dh512.pem 1024
```

Now when I run the server with this configuration, I get that error... what am I doing wrong?

If you require any additional information, please ask.

EDIT:

So I checked the keys as suggested with the commands:

openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server.key
openssl req -noout -modulus -in server.csr
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.crt

And the first two produced the same key, while the last one is different. I have to confirm that the crt file is created using

```
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in server.csr -signkey ../sslca/ca.key -out server.crt
```

Suggestions? I mean if not matching key and certificate is a problem, then my signing method is wrong! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you may wish to be more careful with the use of "certificate" vs. "key". A certificate _contains_ a key pair, but it's not the same. Traditionally, the public key is thought to be part of the certificate. The private key is what should be known as the key, but the private key (obviously)  needs to match the public key (hence the certificate) or it couldn't work. Not sure if this will help, but putting it out there as your wordings left enough room for ambiguity

Comment: *"Traditionally, the public key is thought to be part of the certificate..."* - A X.509 certificate binds a public key to an identity. That is its purpose in life. The public key is always there...

Comment: @jww Sir, could you please explain? I really need help and don't need quotations. What is wrong in what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error output, the first step you could try is to make sure your certificate matches the private key by `openssl` commands. It might be done like this,

```
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server.key
openssl req -noout -modulus -in server.csr
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in server.crt
```

If the modulus are the same, which means the files are matched, then look into boost program. 
Otherwise, there might be a file mix-up.

Comment: This is what I meant too. (What do you mean "look into boost program"?)

Comment: Yes, you are right. And sorry for that unclear expression. I mean, to check/investigate the relevant server.cpp source code in boost.org.

Comment: The key and csr files have the same modulus, but the crt file is different and is longer. I checked how I signed it and it's with `openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in server.csr -signkey ../sslca/ca.key -out server.crt`. Does this look wrong?